# How to Retrieve Another Statement Records Using HashTable?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashtable, language-concepts

Good Evening, I try to use the HashTable() for storing a database table records temporarily . The problem is I dunno why the records which being put inside the HashTable() will always be the first record. I think the problem occur is because of the wrong for loops concept, related code:

> Declare

```
Hashtable hashsample = new Hashtable();
```

> for loop

```
for (i = 0; i< db.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

        hashsample.put(i, db.getData());
        System.out.println(hashsample);
    }
```

p/s: I'm new in HashTable, the db (database statement) run fine...

Need some hints and advised, thanks in advanced^^

Comment: Start with a `Map` in the first place . How do you iterate through the DB resultset ?

Comment: I don't there is an issue in your code. May be the way you are verifying is not correct. Try to print the element and not the hashtable i.e.         System.out.println(hashsample.get(i));

Comment: thanks...I solve it and it is because of my silly mistake...
should change the hashsample.put(i, db.getData()) to ("key", db.getDataAtRow(i))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code mocking the db:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap db = new HashMap();
    db.put(0, "zero");
    db.put(1, "one");
    db.put(2, "two");
    db.put(3, "three");

    Hashtable hashsample = new Hashtable();

    for (int i = 0; i < db.size(); i++) {

            hashsample.put(i, db.get(i));
            System.out.println(hashsample);
    }

}
```

and it works just fine. Here the output:

```
{0=zero}
{1=one, 0=zero}
{2=two, 1=one, 0=zero}
{3=three, 2=two, 1=one, 0=zero}
```

The problem I think is that your db.getData() return always the same thing.

Comment: ya, I still need to do more homework to master the HashTable()...
TQ from the bottom of my heart^^